# Jquery Autocomplete scroll issue in IE11

Tags: jquery, combobox, autocomplete, scrollbar, internet-explorer-11

- Topic: Jquery autocomplete with scrollable results.
- Issue: When we click on the scroll bar down arrow in auto complete results, the scroll is not moving down in IE11. I am able to see this issue in Jquery auto complete demo site itself.([Scroll Issue in IE11](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight))

Is there any work around for this issue.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you found a solution ?

Comment: This is bug and still open. 

https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/15072